# Close a game/app on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

Is there a way of closing games/apps open on Xbox One?

It seems every time after you press the Home button, go out navigate through Home/the main system, and then come back to the game, it is still open, which is good.

However, it seems that it only closes and frees up memory only after you open another game/app.

Does anyone have more information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to do this (it would be weird if you couldn't, really). From [the Xbox Support pages](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/apps/how-to-close-xbox-one-app-or-game):

> If you encounter a problem with an Xbox One app or game, or if you just want to switch to a different one, it’s easy to close the app or game you’re using. Here’s how:
>
> To return to the Home screen, press the Xbox button  to open the guide, and then select Home.
>   Verify that the big application tile is highlighted, and then press the Menu button  on your controller.
>
> Select Quit.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question @Vemonus! I am not a native American, and I really appreciate the opportunity of learning more how to better write and speak English. :)

Comment: @wireless.adapter.rf no problem! Glad I could help :)